# docker build on a private git repo containing the Dockerfile?

Tags: git, github, docker, dockerfile

I have a private git repository on [github.com](http://github.com) and I want to automate the `docker build` process using a `Dockerfile`. I naively thought the best place to have the `Dockerfile` is in the root folder of my repo. Example:

```
git clone ssh://git@github.com/avilella/bioboxes_playground
cd bioboxes_playground
ls Dockerfile
Dockerfile
```

So for external dependencies, I am installing them with `apt-get install` or downloading the tar.gz and installing them during `docker build`.

What's not clear to me is how to expose the code in the repo to the instructions in `docker build`.

I added a simple `hello_world.c` example which is in the repo, and I want to compile during `docker build`. See below:

```
FROM debian:wheezy
MAINTAINER Foo Bar, foo@bar.com

ENV ORG foo
ENV APP bar
ENV INSTALL_DIR /opt/${ORG}/${APP}

ENV PACKAGES wget binutils make csh g++ sed gawk perl zlib1g-dev 
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ${PACKAGES}

ENV SEQTK https://github.com/avilella/seqtk/archive/sgdp.tar.gz

ENV THIRDPARTY_DIR ${INSTALL_DIR}/thirdparty

RUN mkdir -p ${THIRDPARTY_DIR}
RUN cd ${THIRDPARTY_DIR}

# SEQTK

RUN mkdir -p ${THIRDPARTY_DIR}/seqtk && cd ${THIRDPARTY_DIR}/seqtk &&\
    wget --quiet --no-check-certificate ${SEQTK} --output-document - |\
    tar xzf - --directory . --strip-components=1 && \
    make

# COMPILE HELLO_WORLD

RUN gcc hello_world.c -o ${INSTALL_DIR}/helloworld

# define an entry point...
```

Options I thought would work:

1. When doing `docker build` I somehow mount the repo folder inside docker, so that it sees the code I just cloned from my repo, in this case the `hello_world.c` file, and then it will follow the `Dockerfile` instructions. How do I do that?
2. Another option I thought was to do a fresh `git clone` as part of the `Dockerfile` instructions.
3. A third option would be to make a release of my git repo and download a copy of the release with `wget` as a `Dockerfile` instruction.

Which of these is the best way to proceed? Any ideas for better practises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: I agree with ***Ben Whaley*** ADD would be the right option here. You can then use `docker build .` in the root folder of the repository.

2 and 3: Everytime you make a change on hello_world.c you have to commit and push to your remote (when this is a private repo you also have to add ssh keys). Might be ok for you, but it is very impractical when bug fixing something locally.

I had the same thoughts as you had and it took me some time to realise that docker is not made (yet) to handle this nicely.

You may have a look at my shell script (https://github.com/Equanox/docker-auto-build) . It enables you to easily build and run your dockerfiles inside a git repo. You can even store commonly used run cmds inside your dockerfiles. You'll find a example how to use it there.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're right - including the Dockerfile in the root of the repo is indeed a best practice. The workflow looks like this:

1. Clone the repo and change to the directory, as you did in the question.
2. Run `docker build -t <some tag> .` to build the docker image
3. Now use `docker push <some tag>` to push the docker image to your image repository (whether that's on Docker Hub public/private or wherever)

Note that if you want the new images to be built automatically you need to turn to another service. Docker Hub has an [automated builds](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerrepos/#automated-builds) feature that will monitor your git repository and build the image when new commits are detected on the specified branch.

In the Dockerfile you should use the `ADD` instruction to copy your code in to the container.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see your point. The question is, how to I expose the code inside the repo when `docker build` is going through the instructions in `Dockerfile`? Updated my question with an example now.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer. You should use the `ADD` instruction to copy the code in to the container.